# VLC - Sort by multiple columns, e.g. Artist, then Year, then Album

Tags: vlc-media-player, playlists, id3

A two part question, related to playing music in VLC:

1. Can you sort by multiple columns? For example, Artist > Year > Album > Track Number.
2. Is there a way to get VLC to show the year in the playlist?

I would hope there is a plugin that would allow for this, any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you right click the bar ABOVE the tracks (ie. title, duration, artist etc.) and not just the tracks themselves, downloading a nightly build or an older version can help if the column still doesn't appear

Comment: Please read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

No option whatsoever.
[image: Screenshot of playlist]

I had set the year of the songs as 2014 and yet, it didn't show up here on in the Windows 8.1 folder interface. Amazingly, it did show up in the Play Music app of my phone.

Comment: I know that it doesn't show up by default, which is the reason why I'm asking the question :)

Comment: Also, if you're referring to Windows 8.1 folder interface, as in Windows Explorer, there would be a column option - I'm using Windows 7, if you right click on a column there's a More option, from which you can choose a column from a variety of metadata options.